# PackageManager 3.0.2 - Adding Plugins

Tags: cocoa, plugins, installation, addition

I've programed a plugin for an installer package I am planning to use.I've used Apple's Package manager 2.4 (Tiger) before where I could right click packages (*pkg), navigate through the contents folder, create a plugins directory and paste my plugin plus the installersections.plist file. However in version 3.0 (Snow Leopard), I can't click on "Show Package Contents" to add my plugin, the option isn't there in finder.

How can I add plugins?Apple must have thought of some way to do this since this is still offered in Xcode 3?

Comment: I struggled with this, and many other issues with PackageMaker 3. It's my opinion that PackageMaker 3 is probably the worst piece of software that Apple is currently shipping. It's really a disgrace just how awful it is. Bugs filed.

Comment: PackageMaker 3 is the best version yet. It still sucks, and sucks a bit more in Snow Leopard, but versions before 3 sucked a lot more. 3 is simply underdocumented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** possible, although tricky, to install plug-ins into a PackageMaker 3 bundle. You need to go to the **Edit** menu in PackageMaker and open the Flat Package Editor. Open your installer bundle, and insert the plug-in in the appropriate location as you would in the Finder with a 2.0 bundle.

Yes, it's a pain.

Comment: thanks Rob. This worked! :) I think it's quite funny that they released a new package manager but the flat package editor is from 2005 :P Package Manager seems to consist of jumbled up software from all sorts of different years...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install plugins with Package Maker 3. It is easier by using "**Raw Editing Mode**". All you have to do is to install plugins activating the Raw Editing mode **Menu>Project>Raw Editing Mode** and than drag the plugins (Plugnins folder containing bundles and the InstallerSections.plist) to the **Files**.

It is less pain than Flat Package Editor, I think.
Good luck, Bye